# String length added before string when using JSON in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

When I call a PHP file with Ajax and pass a POST variable with a javascript dictionary, the value of this POST variable is parsed to a PHP dictionary. However, the length of the String values is prepended to the String. The same is true for the array. Why is this the case and how can I circumvent this? (When comparing strings PHP thinks the string(x) is part of the string)

EDIT: The string comparison does still work, I would still like to know why this is added though.
EDIT2: I found the answer, this is actually part of [var_dump](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)..

Javascript ajax call:

```
var res = $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
    data: {
      name:"STRING NAME",
      validators:{KEY: "VALUE", KEY2: "VALUE2"}
    },
  url: url,
  dataType: "json",
  async: false,
  success: function(data) {
    result=data;
  }
});
```

Var dump on the receiving end with the PHP

```
array(2) {
  ["KEY"]=>
  string(5) "VALUE"
  ["KEY2"]=>
  string(6) "VALUE2"
}
```

Comment: var_dump _shows_ the type and length in the output it creates, but that does not mean they are part of the actual data.

Comment: I did not understand your problem, it seems its all ok

Comment: Indeed, I just found that it is a part of var_dump. Well, that was quickly solved ;p

Comment: @TomStock exact, thats why it was all ok

Comment: You can use print_r().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example:

```
array(2) {
    ["KEY"]=>
    string(5) "VALUE"
    ["KEY2"]=>
    string(6) "VALUE2"
}
```

you see 'string(5) "VALUE"' because you are printing through var_dump() function.

You should use print_r() function to hide the type of data.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as it turns out this phenomenon is part of `var_dump`. So nothing to worry about.